# Two different XML namespaces with the same URL

Tags: python, xml, database, data-cleaning

I am trying to do some data cleaning using the xml element tree library in python.

My xml input files look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mods:mods xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" version="3.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-5.xsd">
  <mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:title>1971, Human Events</mods:title>
  </mods:titleInfo>
  <mods:name type="personal" authority="naf" valueURI="https://lccn.loc.gov/n88172648">
    <mods:namePart>Kellems, Vivien, 1896-1975</mods:namePart>
    <mods:role>
      <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" authorityURI="http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators" valueURI="http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/col" type="text">Collector</mods:roleTerm>
    </mods:role>
  </mods:name>
  <mods:typeOfResource>text</mods:typeOfResource>
  <mods:genre authority="aat" valueURI="300111999">publications (documents)</mods:genre>
  <mods:originInfo>
    <mods:dateIssued encoding="w3cdtf" keyDate="yes">1971</mods:dateIssued>
  </mods:originInfo>
  <mods:physicalDescription>
    <mods:digitalOrigin>reformatted digital</mods:digitalOrigin>
    <mods:internetMediaType>image/jp2</mods:internetMediaType>
  </mods:physicalDescription>
  <mods:note type="ownership">Archives &amp; Special Collections at the Thomas J. Dodd Research Center, University of Connecticut Library</mods:note>
  <mods:identifier type="local">1992-0033/SeriesIII:Activism/SubseriesA:PoliticalCampaigns/Box138:6</mods:identifier>
  <mods:identifier type="local">MSS 1992.0033</mods:identifier>
  <mods:identifier type="local">39153030468468</mods:identifier>
  <mods:accessCondition type="use and reproduction">In Copyright</mods:accessCondition>
  <mods:recordInfo>
    <mods:recordContentSource>University of Connecticut Library</mods:recordContentSource>
    <mods:recordCreationDate encoding="w3cdtf">2018-07-09-04:00</mods:recordCreationDate>
    <mods:languageOfCataloging>
      <mods:languageTerm authority="iso639-2b" type="code">eng</mods:languageTerm>
    </mods:languageOfCataloging>
  </mods:recordInfo>
  <mods:note type="source note">Vivien Kellems Papers</mods:note>
  <mods:note type="source identifier">MSS 1992.0033</mods:note>
  <identifier type="hdl">http://hdl.handle.net/11134/20002:860633493</identifier>
</mods:mods>
```

All I have to do is change the identifier tag at the end to have the same prefix as the rest of the tags, the "mods" prefix. And to add a specific hlink attribute to the accessCondition tag. I have successfully done both of those things. But after I write these modifications back to the file and try to use the xml element tree parser, I get the following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 25, column 2
```

Now I think this is a namespace issue because the the "xmlns:mods" namespace and the "xmlns" namespace have the same url so when I register the namespace into the parser like so:

```
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")
ET.register_namespace('mods', "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")
ET.register_namespace('xlink', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
ET.register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
```

It also removes one of the namespaces when I write back to the xml file, the namespace declarations look like this:

```
<mods:mods xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-5.xsd">
```

Namely, the "xmlns" declaration. Only the "xmlns:mods" declaration is shown. And again I think this is due to them having the same urls. Is there anyway to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid handling XML transformations especially with namespaces directly in Python with `etree` using `for` loops and `if` logic. Instead, I would run XSLT using Python's third-party `lxml` library. See [demo](https://rextester.com/RAQ65114).

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3` is the namespace. `mods` is nothing but an abbreviation (a.k.a. the "prefix"). You can have as many different abbreviations for the same namespace in your XML document as you want.

For example:

```
<something xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
  <mods:something_else xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" />
  <blah:another_thing xmlns:blah="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" />
  <last_thing />
</something>
```

and

```
<mods:something xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:blah="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
  <something_else xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" />
  <mods:another_thing />
  <blah:last_thing />
</mods:something>
```

and any number of other combinations represent *exactly the same document*.

When those are parsed, and then serialized again, all those namespace declarations could be retained exactly as they are, or they could be folded into a single one, the prefixes could be renamed to `ns0`, or it could be turned into a default namespace - it does not matter. It completely depends on the way the XML library is implemented.

As long as every element in the resulting document is in the `http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3` namespace, it's the same document by any relevant metric:

```
<something xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
  <something_else />
  <another_thing  />
  <last_thing />
</something>
```

In other words, there is nothing broken, so nothing needs to be fixed.